# Return a DataSet from Method

Tags: c#, linq, dataset

I have a method with my query in it. My query is a LINQs query, but I want the method to return a DataSet. Is this possible, if so how you you go about setting that up.

```
private DataSet ListAllData(string distributorId)
{
     var theQuery =  (from r in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("opportunity")  
  join c in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("contact") on ((EntityReference)r["new_contact"]).Id equals c["contactid"] into opp 
  from o in opp.DefaultIfEmpty()
  where ((EntityReference)r["new_channelpartner"]).Id.Equals(distributorId) && ((OptionSetValue)r["new_leadstatus"]).Equals("100000002")
  select new
    {
         OpportunityId = !r.Contains("opportunityid") ? string.Empty : r["opportunityid"],
         CustomerId = !r.Contains("customerid") ? string.Empty : ((EntityReference)r["customerid"]).Name,
         Priority = !r.Contains("opportunityratingcode") ? string.Empty : r.FormattedValues["opportunityratingcode"],
         ContactName = !r.Contains("new_contact") ? string.Empty : ((EntityReference)r["new_contact"]).Name,
         Source = !r.Contains("new_sourcepick") ? string.Empty : r.FormattedValues["new_sourcepick"],

    });
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You have the possibility to use LINQ, you have built a strongly typed object and you want to throw all your efforts away and return a weakly typed DataSet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be of help: [Creating a DataTable From a Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I think that article almost got me there. But I getting this error on the select "Error 52 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.DataRow>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)" Any ideas?

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's hard to say. But in the linked article, look specifically at the section 'Creating a Custom CopyToDataTable<T> Method'. It links to here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx which has an implementation that may help you.